# Getting RelatedManager instead of getting model object by id

Tags: django, model

I have a `Patient` and a `Doctor` model that inherits from django User

```
class HmsUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ characters'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'), _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name();

    def get_profile(self):
        # ....

    def real(self, ):
        try: return self.doctor
        except Doctor.DoesNotExist:
            try: return self.operator
            except Operator.DoesNotExist:
                try: return self.patient
                except Patient.DoesNotExist:
                    try: return self.organization
                    except Organization.DoesNotExist:
                        return self

    def is_doctor(self):
        return self.real().__class__ == Doctor
    
    def is_patient(self):
        return self.real().__class__ == Patient
    
    def is_operator(self):
        return self.real().__class__ == Operator
    
    def is_organization(self):
        return self.real().__class__ == Organization
                    
    def really(self, user_type):
        return isinstance(self.real(), user_type)

class Person(HmsUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name  = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    dob        = models.DateField('Date Of Birth')
    sex        = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    address    = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    image      = models.ImageField(upload_to=rename_image, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    # ....

class Patient(Person):
    def get_full_name(self):
        return '%s. %s' % ( ('Mr', 'Ms')[self.sex == 'F'], super(Patient, self).get_full_name())

    def get_short_name(self):
        return '%s. %s' % (('Mr', 'Ms')[self.sex == 'F'], super(Patient, self).get_short_name())
    
    def admission(self):
        admissions = self.admissions.filter(released = None)
        return admissions.count() > 0 and admissions.latest('admitted') or None
    
    def doctors(self):
        id_list = self.stories.values_list('doctor', flat=True).distinct()
        return Doctor.objects.filter(pk__in=set(id_list))

    def visits(self):
        # ....

    def profile(self):
        return reverse('patient', args=(self.id, ))

class Doctor(Person):
    paramedic     = models.BooleanField()
    specialization = models.CharField(_('Specialization'), max_length=64, blank=True)
    organizations = models.ManyToManyField(Organization, through='Membership', blank=True)
    
    def get_full_name(self):
        return '%s. %s' % ('Dr', super(Doctor, self).get_full_name())

    def get_short_name(self):
        return '%s. %s' % ('Dr', super(Doctor, self).get_short_name())
    
    def stories(self):
        # ....
    
    def patients(self):
        id_list = self.stories.values_list('patient', flat=True).distinct()
        return Patient.objects.filter(pk__in=set(id_list))
    
    def profile(self):
        return reverse('doctor', args=(self.id, ))
```

I have different view for doctor and patient models

```
def patient(request, patient_id):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(id=patient_id)
    print(patient.__class__)        # <class 'identity.models.Patient'>
    print(patient.real().__class__) # <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedManager'>

def doctor(request, doctor_id):
    doctor = Doctor.objects.get(id=doctor_id)
    print(doctor.__class__)        # <class 'identity.models.Doctor'>
    print(doctor.real().__class__) # <class 'identity.models.Doctor'>
```

`doctor.real().__class__` and `doctor.__class__` return `<class 'identity.models.Doctor'>`

**But**

`patient.real().__class__` returns `<class 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedManager'>`

**However**

`patient.__class__` returns `<class 'identity.models.Patient'>`

Why `patient.real().__class__` is not `<class 'identity.models.Patient'>`

**Also** when I open django `shell`

```
In [15]: d = Doctor.objects.get(id=68)    
In [16]: p = Patient.objects.get(id=69)    
In [17]: d.doctor
Out[17]: <Doctor: Dr. Shatadal Saha>    
In [18]: p.patient
Out[18]: <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedManager at 0x7fd86e45ee90>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print `patient.real().__class__` this.

So this return a field from real method that has `Foreignkey` or `ManytoMany` with another Model. So `patient.real().__class__` print Field relation class not self class name

Comment: So this implies through some `related_name` a `Patient` is being related to another `Patient` . But Patient class doesn't have any such related name declared. Or did I overlook ? How do I make sure what is the source of Related Field ?

Comment: but you inherit super HmsUser class that have this type of field

Comment: So this should also apply to Doctor. Because Doctor also inherits HmsUser

Comment: but according to view queryset you sent doctor instance and your real() method have first return related to doctor. but for person instance from your view that not exist doctor in real() method

Comment: did you mean patient instance ? However if `self.patient` is `Related` then `self.doctor` should also be related, irrespective of order of execution

Comment: yes. you have first self.doctor in real() method that return doctor value when you call real from doctor view but when you call real() from patient view then swlf.doctor give DoesNotExist exceptiob maybe so that check next line code of real() that maybe related to Foreignkey key field

Comment: I don't understand may be ForeignKey reasoning, yes it throws a DoesNotExist exception. But there is no ForeignKey named `patient` in `Patient` model

Comment: Can you add all fields of HmsUser class in your question?

Comment: added all fields in HmsUser class

Comment: Update also Patient and Doctor models fields

Comment: 1) Why is missing some Model Method informations like:  def stories(self):
because you defined  self.stories.values_list in both Patient and Doctor models but doctor model have # and Patient model does not have any Information
2) According to shell output  p.patient or d.doctor So where you did defines .doctor or .patient field or method in models ?

Comment: these methods are irrelevant and properties are present for model inheritance, I didn't define them, story model have a doctor field